# Set @ModelAttribute in MockHttpServletRequest in JUnit Test

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, junit, annotations

I'm trying to test a spring mvc controller. One of the methods takes a form input as a POST method.
This method gets the form's commandObject through a `@ModelAttribute` annotation.
How can I set this test case up, using Spring's Junit test?

The controller's method looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String formSubmitted(@ModelAttribute("vote") Vote vote, ModelMap model) { ... }
```

The `Vote`object is defined in the .jsp:

```
 <form:form method="POST" commandName="vote" name="newvotingform">
```

Now I want to test this form POST in a Test which is set up as follows:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:/spring/applicationContext.xml"})
@TestExecutionListeners({WebTestExecutionerListener.class, DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class})
public class FlowTest { ... }
```

The actual method which is testing the form POST:

```
@Test
public void testSingleSession() throws Exception {

    req = new MockHttpServletRequest("GET", "/vote");
    res = new MockHttpServletResponse();
    handle = adapter.handle(req, res, vc);
    model = handle.getModelMap();

    assert ((Vote) model.get("vote")).getName() == null;
    assert ((Vote) model.get("vote")).getState() == Vote.STATE.NEW;

    req = new MockHttpServletRequest("POST", "/vote");
    res = new MockHttpServletResponse();

    Vote formInputVote = new Vote();
    formInputVote.setName("Test");
    formInputVote.setDuration(45);

    //        req.setAttribute("vote", formInputVote);
    //        req.setParameter("vote", formInputVote);
    //        req.getSession().setAttribute("vote", formInputVote);

    handle = adapter.handle(req, res, vc) ;
    model = handle.getModelMap();

    assert "Test".equals(((Vote) model.get("vote")).getName());
    assert ((Vote) model.get("vote")).getState() == Vote.STATE.RUNNING;
}
```

The 3 lines which are currently commented out, are feeble attempts to make this work - it did not work however.
Can anyone provide some tips on this?

I don't really want to call the controllers method directly in my test as I feel like this would not really test the controller in a web context.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to simulate what your HTML form will do. It will simply pass string request parameters. Try:

```
req.setParameter("name","Test");
req.setParameter("duration","45");
```

Answer (score 7):

With Spring MVC 3, you can use something along this line:

```
        mockMvc.perform(post("/secretSauce")
            .param("password", "123")
            .sessionAttr("sessionData", "tomato"))
            .andDo(print())
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
```

Comment: I would use `flashAttr("vote", new Vote())` instead of `sessionAttr()`