# Testing a post request

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, junit

In below question I am I am confused by line :   `handle = adapter.handle(req, res, vc);`

[Set @ModelAttribute in MockHttpServletRequest in JUnit Test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6339777/set-modelattribute-in-mockhttpservletrequest-in-junit-test)

How/where is the `adapter` object instantiated ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both the `adapter` and the `WebTestExecutionerListener` seem to be the OPs own code. There's no way of knowing short of asking him.

Answer (score 3):

The adapter object that he is referring to is a [HandlerAdapter](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerAdapter.html) from the SpringSource docs. More specifically, it is the subclass [AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/annotation/AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.html)

I also wanted to test my RESTful service in Spring MVC. Below are two links that were really helpful to me:

[Unit Testing Controllers in Spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401128/how-to-unit-test-a-spring-mvc-controller-using-pathvariable)

[Using HandlerAdapter in integration tests](http://www.scarba05.co.uk/blog/2010/03/integration-testing-of-springs-mvc-annotation-mapppings-for-controllers/)